# How to simulate a simple join in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections corresponding to company information and each has information that the other does not have. So all I want to do is simply merge the two collections into one collection having all the information.

**Example:**

*Collection_1* has records like

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f7db2adfa8c217420d32560"
  },
  "Company": "moby group",
  "Country": "Afghanistan",
  "Industry": "Media",
  "Status": "Done",
  "Links": [
    "https://mobygroup.com/",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Media_Group",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby",
    "https://www.amazon.com/Moby-Group-Darya/dp/B08BLQDRTZ"
  ]
}
```

*Collection_2* has records like

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5faa792d78a49486fdf4f605"
  },
  "Company": "moby group",
  "domain": "mobygroup.com",
  "year founded": 2003,
  "industry": "broadcast media",
  "size range": "201-500",
  "country": "afghanistan",
  "linkedin url": "linkedin.com/company/moby-group",
  "current employee estimate": 165,
  "total employee estimate": 324
}
```

I want to merge *Collection_1* and *Collection_2* on the company name into one collection to look like:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "..."
  },
  "Company": "moby group",
  "domain": "mobygroup.com",
  "year founded": 2003,
  "industry": "broadcast media",
  "size range": "201-500",
  "country": "afghanistan",
  "linkedin url": "linkedin.com/company/moby-group",
  "current employee estimate": 165,
  "total employee estimate": 324,
  "Status": "Done",
  "Links": [
    "https://mobygroup.com/",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Media_Group",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby",
    "https://www.amazon.com/Moby-Group-Darya/dp/B08BLQDRTZ"
  ]
}
```

To put it in words I want all the fields from Collection 2 coupled with "Status" and "Links" fields from Collection 1. From my research, I discovered that MongoDB does not allow one to easily do this and I see that there is some hacky way to go about it using the lookup and unwind aggregate but I am unable to wrap my mind around the flow.

Could someone explain to me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to merge collections.

And you need a query similar to this:

```js
db.coll2.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "coll1",
      "localField": "Company",
      "foreignField": "Company",
      "as": "joinCollection"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Status": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$joinCollection.Status",
          0
        ]
      },
      "Links": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$joinCollection.Links",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "joinCollection"
  }
])
```

This query do a `join` between two collections using `$lookup`. It merges the collections by `Company` field and store into a variable called `joinCollection`.

After that, the query add the fields you want: `Status` and `Links` and delete the field `joinColeection` to get the object as you want.

Here is an [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b6uL3EhapMj)